# Textillate Plugin Syntax error on token "in", IntegerLiteral expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, eclipse, plugins

I am using the [Textillate](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Text-Animation-Plugin-with-CSS3/) plugin for animation of my text in a web application. However when i define the **javascript** for the animation i am getting a Syntax error in **Eclipse** by 'in' definition. How can i get **Eclipse** to recognize the `'in'` definition and not throw a syntax error?

**Syntax Error**

```
Syntax error on token "in", IntegerLiteral expected
```

**Code**

```
$(function () {
    $('.userOption').textillate({       

         selector: '.texts', // the default selector to use when detecting multiple texts to animate
          loop: true, // enable looping
          minDisplayTime: 2000, // sets the minimum display time for each text before it is replaced
          initialDelay: 0,  // sets the initial delay before starting the animation
          autoStart: true,  // set whether or not to automatically start animating
          inEffects: [], // custom set of 'in' effects. This effects whether or not the character is shown/hidden before or after an animation 
          outEffects: [ 'rollOut' ],   // custom set of 'out' effects

          // in animation settings
          in: {
            effect: 'rotateInUpLeft', // set the effect name
            delayScale: 1.5, // set the delay factor applied to each consecutive character
            delay: 50, // set the delay between each character
            sync: false,  // set to true to animate all the characters at the same time
            shuffle: false  // randomize the character sequence (note that shuffle doesn't make sense with sync = true)
          },

          // out animation settings.
          out: {
            effect: 'rollOut',
            delayScale: 1.5,
            delay: 50,
            sync: false,
            shuffle: true,
          }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#in) is a reserved JavaScript [keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords).

Rename the property, or wrap the name in quotes.